# Index into the "fraction table" and back

Tags: math, fractions

Suppose the following array of fractions:

```
1/2, 1/3, 2/3, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4, 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1/6, ...
```

Creating an array like this is pretty trivial:

```js
for (var i = 2; i < 100: i ++) {
   for (var j = 1; j < i; j ++) {
      console.log(j / i);
   }
}
```

I would like to transform an "index" to this array into a floating point number, **without using a lookup table**, such that:

- 0 = 0.5
- 6 = 0.125
- 10 = 0.833

Comment: The numerator and denominator follow fairly [simple](http://oeis.org/A002260) [patterns](http://oeis.org/A003057). It shouldn't be too hard to figure out an answer.

Comment: Ive been on this for a while, if you can figure something out it would appreciated!

Comment: Why is `3/5` not included, but `3/6` is included when `1/2` already was, and `1/6` is not included? There is no obvious pattern that I can see.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong. Read the sequence now

Comment: @deprilula28 The pages I linked to contain simple formulas for calculating the nth numerator and the nth denominator. What are you finding so difficult?

Comment: This page needs some serious re formating, but I was able to solve it, thank you!